# Java NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, maven, noclassdeffounderror

I am working in a "biggish" Maven/Java project and cannot make sense of an error I am getting when running the app (it compiles OK). The error code I get is:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.management.OperatingSystem
  at com.sun.management.OSMBeanFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean(OSMBeanFactory.java:30)
        at sun.management.ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean(ManagementFactory.java:100)
        at sun.management.ManagementFactory.createPlatformMBeanServer(ManagementFactory.java:308)
        at java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer(ManagementFactory.java:504)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.JMXAgent.<init>(JMXAgent.java:49)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.JMXAgent.getDefault(JMXAgent.java:77)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl.<clinit>(WSEndpointImpl.java:84)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
```

From the look of it, it seems the VM is not finding the "com.sun.management.OperatingSystem" class, but after googling around I cannot find out where is that class supposed to be located.

Any hints?

**EDIT:** Running with JRE JDK 1.6.0_18 (JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_18)

Comment: Under which version of Java are you running the application?

Comment: Can you post your relevant portions of your maven and start-up script as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might not be what's causing your problem, but errors like the one you are seeing can sometimes occur when the JDK is stored under "Program Files". Java doesn't like spaces in the filesystem path.

Answer (score 0):

com.sun.management is an undocumented java package. The class OperatingSystem is the implementation for the OperatingSystemMXBean. If you download the Javasource code you will be able to see the class there.

As far as the location of this file, it should be in your standard JRE package. Make sure your application is pointing to the proper JRE. In Java 5/6, the class can be found in the rt.jar file.

If you want to confirm the file is there, Open the jar in program like [JD-Gui](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui) and have a look around the Jar to confirm.

Comment: Yup, OperatingSystem.class and all the other files under "rt.jar\com\sun\management - ZIP archive" are there. So it seems the error is not produced by that

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the javadocs for Java 6 and 7, it appears that OSMBeanFactory (which is in your stack trace) was added in 7.

[Monitoring and Management Interface for the Java™ Platform (6)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/management/extension/)

[Monitoring and Management Interface for the Java™ Platform DRAFT ea-b120 (7)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/management/extension/)

Comment: it may not have been documented, but it is in the jar files. As far back as 5 for what i can see